# How to know which line is causing exception?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, lldb

I am new to XCode and Objective C. I have ***intentionally*** make a mistake to assign number to NSString*.

```
NSString* s = @1;
[s uppercaseString];
```

Though XCode gives me warning, this code will compile. But at runtime I get exception. Now I see in logs, *(Sorry for image, I was not able to paste is as text properly due to formatting)*

[image]

In this log, how I find exact place of error. How this log tells me which code to change.

Comment: You cannot create string with object C literal like that. It creates NSNumber but upperCaseString is NSString method. You better create string like NSString *s = @"1"

Comment: You should be receiving 'Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSString *' with an expression of type 'NSNumber *'' warning for your first statement.

Comment: @insane-36 I mentioned, I intentionally did it. I wanted to understand how XCode gives me logs of exception.

Comment: See in the exception it clearly says [_NSCFNumber uppercaseString] unrecognized selector passed to instance, _NSCFNumber is runtime class for NSNumber.

Comment: See http://raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand what line causes the problem, you usually need to add exception breakpoint to your project as explained in [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html);

1. In the bottom-left corner of the breakpoints navigator, click the
   Add button.
2. Choose Add Exception Breakpoint.
3. In the Exception pop-up menu, choose the type of exception on which
   you want execution to stop:

   - All. Stops on all exceptions.
   - Objective-C. Stops on Objective-C exceptions.
   - C++. Stops on C++ exceptions. To stop on a particular C++ exception, specify the exception name.
4. Choose the phase of the exception handling process at which you want program execution to stop.
5. Click Done.

Answer (score 7):

So it looks like you are running the Release build (debug symbols stripped) and if you got that crash log in a production environment you would need to symbolicate it in order to find the line.

This [Apple TN](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html) gives some details of Symbolication.

In a development environment you would simply add an exception breakpoint and run it from Xcode, as the debug symbols would not be stripped.

Answer (score 2):

line 5 Sam : [BIDViewController viewDidLoad] + 143 , if this is a release build , you need to resolve with symbols the memory address of the function , this is called "symbolize" the crash dump...

Answer (score 2):

In the log look for your project name and you will come to know.

e.g.

```
line 5 Sam : [BIDViewController viewDidLoad] + 143
```

If you want to produce real crash without warning, try following code it will produce index out of bound exception and will crash

```
NSArray *array = @[@"1",@"2"];
NSLog(@"Item not accessible->%@",(NSString*)array[2]);
```

Answer (score 2):

set Exception breaking point or enable NSZombie object

[image]

or

NSZombie

From the menu bar, choose Project > Scheme > Edit Scheme

[image]